# Call method from child Class

Tags: java, methods, casting

I am trying something like this:

```
public class Dog {
}

public class Cat extends Dog {
    private void mew() {
    }
}

Dog d = new Dog();
d.mew();
```

During runtime d will contain a cat object due to other methods but I can't compile.

Comment: No, `d` contains a reference to a `Dog` instance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And `d` is a Dog not a Cat.

Comment: First, you can't access private methods outside of your class. Second, the `Dog` class has no `mew()` method declared, so it makes sense that it doesn't compile.

Comment: Although you probably just used `Dog` and `Cat` as example class names, `Cat` is a `Dog` makes no sense as a relationship.

Comment: Well in my case Im programming a game. There is a normal Stone and a special Stone. The special Stone has some extra methods. Another class holds the stones as Variables and they can change. So at runtime a Stone will be a special Stone. So a Cat is not a Dog in my case but Java thinks it is...

Comment: `d.mew` even if it existed needs to be in a code block (i.e. a method or constrcutor or static block)

Comment: Cat extends dog and not dog extends cat so a dog can't  `mew()`.

Comment: @FabianZbinden Perhaps explain what you're trying to achieve in more detail. If you want 'special stone' to do something different from 'normal stone' but wish to type them all as stone (or normal stone) then you want to make use of polymorphism through overriding as opposed to introducing new methods in the sub-classes.

Comment: The variable d is declared as Dog, therefor if the reference changes to an instance of Cat and you want to call `.mew()` you need to make a cast, i.e. `(Cat)d.mew()` but you need to change access of `mew()` from private to public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In should initialize `Dog` with `Cat` instance (or `Stone` with `SpecialStone` instance):

```
Stone s = new SpecialStone();
```

Then you can call the method on your `SpecialStone` (This can work only if you initialize parent by child class):

```
if (s instanceof SpecialStone) {
   (SpecialStone)s.specialMethod();
}
```

Another way is use of polymorphism:

```
public class Stone {
   public void specialMethod() {

   }
}

public class SpecialStone {
   @Override
   public void specialMethod() {
   }
}
```

But it will add `specialMethod` to every instance of `Stone`

Comment: Looks more like what I want. But now I need a boolean return from SpecialStone in a ifStatement:

`else if (field.getStone().getAttacks(board).size() > 0 && (field.getStone().isDame() && (StoneDame)!field.getStone().isJustTurned()))`

Comment: Which method is in `SpecialStone` ? What do you want to achieve? To access method in child `SpecialStone` you just need to cast your `Stone` to child class (given that your `Stone` is initialized with your child class)

Comment: the `public boolean isJustTurned()` method is in the `StoneDame` class. 

The `Field` class contains a Variable `private Stone stone` because normally it only contains normal stones. In rare cases it contains `StoneDame` wich extends `Stone`.

Comment: then put an `instanceof` check before the cast

Comment: `Boolean b = true;
        if(field.getStone() instanceof StoneDame){b = (StoneDame)field.getStone().isJustTurned();}`
Does not work even out of the whole if statement.

Comment: As I said, your `field.getStone()` must be initialized with `new StoneDame()` before. Otherwise, if you initialize with `new Stone()` then it will not work because `field.getStone() instanceof StoneDame` return false

Comment: It needed to be like this:
`((StoneDame)field.getStone()).isJustTurned())`

Brackets were missing... classic.

Answer (score 0):

Its the other way around.

`Dog` is a parent class, so it actually doesn't know that some class `Cat` extends it, and it doesn't know about the methods of a classes extending it.

However `Cat` extends `Dog` and it knows about all non-private methods of a `Dog` + its own methds.

So you couldn't call `mew()` from `Dog`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface that defines the methods for a "Stone" and then use different implementations for a NormalStone or a SpecialStone.
See my example:

```
public interface Stone {
    int getValue(); 
}

public class NormalStone implements Stone {

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class SpecialStone implements Stone {


    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return 100;
    }
}

public class Game {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<Stone> stones = new ArrayList<>();
        stones.add(new NormalStone());
        stones.add(new SpecialStone());

        for (final Stone stone : stones) {
            System.out.println(stone.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```